# Export PDF from Illustrator at a specific resolution

Tags: export

I want to export my file from Illustrator as High Quality PDF for print with VistaPrint. So I want to export, and select High Quality PDF.
But the PDF quality is 600 x 800 px and I need at least 2517 x 3544 px.
How can I change that?

Comment: How are you determining the "PDF quality is 600x800"?

Comment: What are your PDF export settings? Is your Illustrator document all vector, or are there raster elements?  Vector graphics have no resolution.

Comment: @Metis : After saving it and in the doc info

Comment: @BillyKerr I have some vector and an image (high res)

Comment: @Joce what are your pdf export settings?  The output resolution will depend on your settings.

Comment: Hey @BillyKerr, i set the export at 300 DPI.

Comment: @Joce - have you tried the "High Quality Print" preset in the Save As Adobe PDF dialog?

Answer (score 1):

PDFs saved from Illustrator are always at the same size they are in your Illustrator document. Any pixel measurements you see inside Illustrator are actually just points; Illustrator assumes 1pt = 1/72 inch and for convenience assumes 1px = 1pt. But vectors have no real concept of pixels or resolution so pixel measurements inside of Illustrator should mostly be ignored unless your final output is a raster image.

Your final artwork, at 213 × 300 mm works out as 603.78 × 850.39 pt. Which Illustrator will show you as the pixel size too, but that *is* the correct size. That will only be the pixel size of your artwork if you export it to a 72 PPI raster image; which you *aren't* doing.

If you have any raster images *within* your Illustrator document, then *they* need to be at minimum that size, and you need to make sure any raster effects are rendered at the correct resolution...

So all you need to do is:

- Make sure your artboard is 213 × 300 mm
- Make sure any placed raster artwork is a minimum of 300 PPI
- Set your PDF (on the "Compression" tab of the PDF save dialog) to either not downsample images or downsample to a minimum of 300 PPI
- Set your raster effect resolution (*Effect → Document Raster Effects Settings*) to 300 PPI